# Adding to every row value based on previous value

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

| Id | Week | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |

Where count is the number of times week appears for the ID:

```
Count = df %>% group_by(Id, Week) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

What I would like to do is to add a column that for every Id and every week, if there is at least one row with the previous week (Week - 1) it would show the previous week's Count, else, 0.

So something like this:

| Id | Week | Count | Count_Prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

How could I create something like Count_Prev?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you are using `df %>% group_by(Id, Week) %>% summarise(count=n())` you should get only 1 row for every `Id` and `Week` combination. Why do you have multiple rows for 1 and 3 & 2 and 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

For each `Id` if the difference between current week number and previous week number is 1, get previous week numbers `Count`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Count_Prev = ifelse(Week - lag(Week, default = first(Week)) == 1,
                      lag(Count), 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your dataset:

```
df %>%
  count(Id, Week, name = "Count") %>%
  arrange(Id, Week) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Prev_Count = ifelse(Week - 1 == lag(Week, default = -1), lag(Count), 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("Id", "Week"))

# A tibble: 11 x 4
      Id  Week Count Prev_Count
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
 1     1     1     1          0
 2     1     3     2          0
 3     1     3     2          0
 4     1     4     1          2
 5     1     8     1          0
 6     2     2     3          0
 7     2     2     3          0
 8     2     2     3          0
 9     2     3     1          3
10     2     4     2          1
11     2     4     2          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unique combinations of Id and Week

```
df=df[!duplicated(df[,c("Id","Week")]),]

df$Id_lag=c(NA,head(df$Id,-1))
df$Week_lag=c(NA,head(df$Week,-1))
df$Count_lag=c(NA,head(df$Count,-1))
df$Count_Prev=ifelse(df$Id==df$Id_lag & df$Week-1==df$Week_lag, df$Count_lag, 0)

df[,c("Id","Week","Count","Count_Prev")]

   Id Week Count Count_Prev
1   1    1     1         NA
2   1    3     2          0
4   1    4     1          2
5   1    8     1          0
6   2    2     3          0
9   2    3     1          3
10  2    4     2          1
```